# MQTT PubSubClient connection problem with ESP32

Tags: esp32, mqtt

I am experiencing some problems with string in Arduino application with ESP32.
I don't understand why this code works:

`mqtt.setServer ("m20.cloudmqtt.com", port);  //is OK`

and this does not work does not connect

`String strSBM = "m20.cloudmqtt.com";
mqtt.setServer (strSBM.c_str (), port);  //no OK`

I use library PubSubClient 2.7

Any of you can help me

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you set the server from a C string it doesn't copy the string - it just retains a pointer to it:

```
PubSubClient& PubSubClient::setServer(const char * domain, uint16_t port) {
    this->domain = domain;
    this->port = port;
    return *this;
}
```

If the string it's pointing to goes out of scope (it's a local variable and the function finishes) the data for the string will be invalidated and lost.

It is really intended to work with string literals and global constant variables that never change.

If this is the one and only time that you ever set the server you could get away with using `strdup()` to duplicate the string data on the heap, but without direct access to the `domain` member variable of the `PubSubClient` class you have no way to `free()` the memory again should you ever wish to change the server.

```
String strSBM = "m20.cloudmqtt.com";
mqtt.setServer (strdup(strSBM.c_str()), port);
```

To make it so you can `free` the value you need to keep track of it separately:

```
static char *temp = NULL;
if (temp != NULL) {
    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;
}
temp = strdup(strSBM.c_str());
mqtt.setServer(temp, port);
```

Comment: same problem for the port number
what function should i use for the port?

Thanks for your help

Comment: No, not the same problem for the port number - that's just a number and gets copied. The problem only exists for the server name because that is a pointer.

Comment: Ok now everything seems to work with client.setServer (strdup (strSBM.c_str ()), (int) strPSBM.toInt ());

Comment: As long as you only ever do that once it's fine - if you do it more than once you have created a memory leak and you will crash after a while. Why exactly do you want the server name in a `String` though?

Comment: Ohh, then this is not good for me, because in my project I save the name of the server and number port to an external EEPROM and I have the possibility to change the configuration parameters. So having static parameters is not good. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Create a global `char` array to store the data in. Read it from the EEPROM into that char array, then pass that to the setServer as is.  Any time you change the contents of that char array the PubSubClient library will instantly see the new data - all that is left is then to connect again.

Comment: Nice idea but my project is too complicated for this change.
What do you think of this lease
char * temp;
free(temp);
temp = strdup(strSBM.c_str ());
client.setServer (temp, 15534);

so that each time I change the parameters of the empty server with free() ??? an idea help help help

Comment: Sure, that could work - as long as `temp` is global or static so it remains all the time. `static char *temp = NULL; if (temp != NULL) { free(temp); temp = NULL; } temp = strdup(strSBM.c_str());` - It's important to check that `temp` actually has something allocated to it before trying to `free` it...